# How can I make a time lapse video out of these images?

Tags: photos, timelapse

I took a bunch of digital images(in .jpg format) of a sunrise that I want to make into a time lapse movie.  How can I make a time lapse video out of these images?

Ideally taking into account the metadata in the image that indicates what time the image was taken when determining how long to display each frame, as they won't be accurately consistent in their temporal spacing. Perhaps with onion skinning/tweening.

Comment: The voting system **isn't used to create polls** but to determine which is the most helpful/correct answer. Since this is a poll, it's best to check the box that says "community wiki".

Comment: Actually the voting system is used in this way quite a bit on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/230/21

Comment: @Rowland Will take a look in more detail, but this looks like it's dealing with stitching multiple images into a single image, where this question is asking about stitching images taken sequentially over a period of time are made into a movie.  Kind of different things, although the intersting thing is that there is probably some image process algorithms for normalizing the colors/brightness/contrast that would be useful in both places.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question -- I'm sure some of the folks on the Photo SE site would be able to answer you though :)

Comment: Hi AaronLS, I removed that blurb in the previous revision so we could potentially keep it on topic; asking for features in a program as specific as that may keep this closed as off topic (product recommendation). I would recommend rolling it back, personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the opensource MakeAVI from http://makeavi.sourceforge.net/

Extremely basic features, but it is free unlike most of the other software of this kind that I've found.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualDub allows you to open an image sequence and you can then modify the video, set framerates, filters etc and finally save the video in various video formats/codecs.

http://www.virtualdub.org/

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Photolapse](http://home.hccnet.nl/s.vd.palen/index.html).  From [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5362108/photolapse-makes-time+lapse-movie-creation-a-snap):

> PhotoLapse is a tiny and portable application for stitching together images into a time-lapse video. Point it at a folder full of pictures, and you're mostly done.
>
> All your time-lapse options are
>   displayed in a single pane when you
>   launch the 158k application. Select
>   your directory of videos, load the
>   images from that directory, and then
>   tweak a few small settings like
>   whether or not you want every image to
>   be included or every Nth image.

Answer (score 1):

[Avidmux (http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/)](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) can output a sequence of images to a movie. Movie type and setting are configurable.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.trevorshp.com/photography/timelapse_videos/timelapse_howto.htm

Use Mencoder (third option on that webpage). It's much easier than anything I've found. It's encoding a time lapse video for me that contains over 720,000 images. Very flexible and the instructions are easy to follow.